# NUnit Console command line regex case insensitive?

Tags: regex, jenkins, mono, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm running NUnit tests on Jenkins/Mono and this is what my command looks like:

```
mono /opt/NUnit-3.8.0/nunit3-console.exe $WORKSPACE/ProjectName/bin/$CONFIG/ProjectName.dll --where="test~=$TEST_NAME" --config=$CONFIG
```

The idea is to be able to select tests using a regular expression. Now, I want to select tests with Regex but ignoring case. I tried something like this:

```
TEST_NAME = ^.*(?i)something(?-i).*$
```

And also tried:

```
TEST_NAME = ^.*something.*$/i
```

But I got the "unexpected token '('" and "unexpected token '/'" errors. Is there any way to use a case-insensitive modifier?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the command-line and/or where clause after the substitution of TEST_NAME occurs. See the XML output or the console output from NUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NUnit [console runner](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) `--where=EXPRESSION` uses a specific [test selection language](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) (TSL) where

> an expression indicating which tests to run. It may specify test
>   names, classes, methods, categories or properties comparing them to
>   actual values with the operators ==, !=, =~ and !~.
>
> For matching regular expressions, NUnit users .NET's Regex.IsMatch
>   method... as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try it like this and check out the samples in the linked TSL doc above.

```
--where "test =~ /(?i).*mytest/"
```

However, if you are using NUnit V2 you are probably out of luck:

> The driver for NUnit V2 supports a subset of TSL. Because the V2 NUnit
>   framework only allowed filtering on test names and categories, you may
>   only use the cat and test keywords in comparisons. In addition, **the
>   regular expression operators =~ and !~ are not supported**.

Comment: I'm using NUnit 3. This works for me to run all tests:
```--where "test=~^.*$"``` and this also works: ```--where "test=~^.*something.*$"``` but as soon as I use (?i) I got the error: ```Unexpected token '(' at position 23 in selection expression.```

Comment: @NatashaTheodoraPetrus I have tested this end-to-end; the where filter works for me as described above. Please, check again.

Comment: I ended up deleting the Jenkins project and writing configurations and commands from scratch, and yes it does work. Not sure what was causing the error yesterday, thanks. Accepting your answer.